# Click events to update gridview inside update panel not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, postback

I have a gridview and a popup modal inside an update panel.

When the gridview cell is clicked, the modal popup will show up and will contain info from that cell.

After that, click events outside the gridview cannot be fired anymore.

Please help.

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"> GO</asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="inventoryUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton1" />
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="cancelButton"/>

        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:GridView ID="inventoryGridview" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="inventoryGridview_RowDataBound"
                OnRowCommand="inventoryGridview_RowCommand" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8.5pt"
                CssClass="inventoryGridviewCSS">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="ColumnClick" Visible="false" />
                </Columns>
                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8.5pt" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>


<div id="viewDetailsDiv" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnPopUp" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="viewDetails" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnPopUp"
        PopupControlID="pnlpopup" CancelControlID="CancelButton" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
        OnLoad="viewDetails_Load">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" BackColor="White">
        <table style="border: Solid 3px black; width: 260px; height: 250px; font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 14; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr style="background-color: #7AC7F0">
                <td colspan="2" style="height: 2px; color: White; font-weight: bold;" align="center">
                    DETAILS
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #7AC7F0">
                <td colspan="2" style="height: 2px; color: White; font-weight: bold;" align="center">
                    <asp:Label ID="roomLabel" runat="server" Text="Room"></asp:Label>
                    -
                    <asp:Label ID="dateLabel" runat="server" Text="Date"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="allotmentLabel" runat="server" Text="Allotment: "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="allotmentTextBox" runat="server" Height="20px" MaxLength="1" onkeypress="return isWholeNumber(event)"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="allotmentRangeValidator" Display="Dynamic" Type="Integer"
                        MaximumValue="5" MinimumValue="1" EnableClientScript="true" ControlToValidate="allotmentTextBox"
                        runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="May allot from 1-5 rooms only."
                        ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="10px"></asp:RangeValidator>
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="reservedLabel" runat="server" Text="Reserved: "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="reservedTextBox" runat="server" Enabled="false" Height="20px" onkeypress="return isWholeNumber(event)"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="availableLabel" runat="server" Text="Available: "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="availableTextBox" runat="server" Enabled="false" Height="20px" onkeypress="return isWholeNumber(event)"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="rateLabel" runat="server" Text="Rate: "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="rateTextBox" runat="server" Height="20px" MaxLength="9" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rateRegularExpressionValidator" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="rateTextBox" ValidationExpression="^\d{0,8}(\d\.\d?|\.\d)?\d?$"
                        ErrorMessage="Invalid input." Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red"
                        Font-Size="10px"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="rateRangeValidator" Display="Dynamic" Type="Double" MaximumValue="999999999"
                        MinimumValue="1" EnableClientScript="true" ControlToValidate="rateTextBox" runat="server"
                        SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Rate cannot be zero (0)." ForeColor="Red"
                        Font-Size="10px"></asp:RangeValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center" height="10px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <asp:Button ID="saveButton" runat="server" Text="SAVE" Width="80px" />
                    <asp:Button ID="cancelButton" runat="server" Text="CANCEL" Width="80px" OnClick="cancelButton_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

<div>
    <asp:Label ID="selectedRoom" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="selectedDate" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div id="previousNext">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="previousLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="previousLinkButton_Click">Previous 21 days</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="nextLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="nextLinkButton_Click">Next 21 days</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your source code..

Comment: @tarzanbappa just edited my post.